# Want to read input by Id instead of by name

Tags: javascript, php, payment-gateway, 2checkout

i want javascript live read my input field by "id"
because payment gateway not allow to add name in input field

```
formSelectors: {
              numberInput: 'input[name="number"]',
              expiryInput: 'input[name="expiry"]',
              cvcInput: 'input[name="cvc"]',
              nameInput: 'input[name="name"]';
            }
```

Comment: `javascript live read my input field by "id"`=>clear out  javascript or jQuery?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got solution here is so simple change name to id

```
formSelectors: {
          numberInput: 'input[id="number"]',
          expiryInput: 'input[id="expiry"]',
          cvcInput: 'input[id="cvc"]',
          nameInput: 'input[id="name"]'
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer:

```
formSelectors: {
              numberInput: '#yourInputId'
            }
```

In addition:

other options to get element by id:

```
document.getElementById("yourInputId")
```

Plus every element that has Id is already selected by JavaScript and stored in variables with same names as id. for example

```
<div id="myid"></div>
```

You will have variable `myid` in javascript and can use it

```
console.log (myid.classList) // array of classes
```